# Having trouble sorting a vector of an ADT by attribute with std::sort() and lambda function

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda, stdvector

I'm trying to sort a vector of my class several times by different attributes within my class.

I have a class "Hitboxes" that has a vector of class "Character" as a data member.  Character has attributes string name_, string type_, int length_, and int width_.  My goal is to be able to sort this vector in the Hitboxes class by each of the attributes within Character.  To accomplish this I'm using the std::sort() function along with a lambda function for comparison as follows for sorting by string type_:

```
       std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                  [](const Character &a, const Character &b) { return a.type_ < b.type_; });
```

However this isn't sorting my vector at all.  According to everything I've read on other posts this should work.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or correct any misconception that I may have regarding the std::sort() function or lambda functions?

```
class Character {
public:
    Character() : name_(""), type_(""), length_(0), width_(0) {}
    Character(std::string name,std::string type,int length, int width) : name_(name), type_(type), length_(length), width_(width) {}
    ~Character() {}

    const std::string& getName() { return name_; }
    const std::string& getType() { return type_; }
    const int& getLength() { return length_; }
    const int& getWidth() { return width_; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Character e) {
        os << e.name_ << "\t" << e.type_ << "\t" << e.length_ << "\t" << e.width_;
        return os;
    }

    int getHitboxSize() { return (length_ * width_); }

    friend class Hitboxes;

    std::string name_;
    std::string type_;
    int length_;
    int width_;
};
```

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "Character.h"

#ifndef Hitboxes_h
#define Hitboxes_h

class Hitboxes {
public:
    Hitboxes( std::string fileName ) {
        std::string name = "", type = "";
        int length = 0, width = 0;
        Character* e = NULL;
        std::fstream iFile(fileName);

        if( iFile.is_open() ) {
            std::cout << "Initializing class from file...\n\n";
            while( iFile >> name >> type >> length >> width ) {
                std::cout << name << " " << type << " " << length << " " << width << std::endl;
                e = new Character(name,type,length,width);
                vec.push_back(*e);                       //
            }
            iFile.close();
            std::cout << "\nInitialization finished!\n\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Couldn't open the file: " << fileName << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~Hitboxes() {}

    std::string smallestType() {
        std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                  [](const Character &a, const Character &b) { return a.type_ < b.type_; });

        return std::to_string(vec[0].getHitboxSize());
    }

    void print() {
        for(Character e : vec)
            std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }

private:
    size_t size;
    std::vector<Character> vec;
};


#endif /* Hitboxes_h */
```

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Hitboxes hb("myFile.txt");
    hb.smallestType();
    hb.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not receiving any errors but the goal is sort the vector in different ways.
For example, to sort by the attribute type_ would have output like:

```
Caustic Defense 13 5
Gibraltar Defense 10 8
Lifeline Defense 8 5
Bloodhound Scout 8 5
Pathfinder Scout 10 6
Bangalore Soldier 11 4
Mirage Soldier 11 4
Wraith Soldier 8 4
```

but instead what I get for output is:

```
Bloodhound Scout 8 5
Pathfinder Scout 10 6
Lifeline Defense 8 5
Gibraltar Defense 10 8
Mirage Soldier 11 4
Bangalore Soldier 11 4
Wraith Soldier 8 4
Caustic Defense 13 5
```

Any other unrelated constructive criticism on my code is welcomed.

Comment: Perhaps you can pare this down a bit to just the code you need to demonstrate the problem and an example of how you are filling these in with data. [mcve]

Comment: You might also take a look at your assignment operator. It's wrong, and based on your class you don't need it, the default is fine.

Comment: Note: Sort is pretty expensive, usually much more expensive than searching through the list for a particular item. Unless you sort once and keep the list sorted for multiple searches, you're wasting your time. Worse, some sorting algorithms have particularly bad behaviour when used on an already sorted list, turning the typical case N log(N) complexity into the worst case N-squared. [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) is probably the better option here.

Comment: Addendum to @RetiredNinja 's comment: Familiarize yourself with the [Rules of Three, Five, and Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). One of the best things you can do as a C++ programmer is to observe the Rules of Three and Five as close to resources as possible so that the majority of your code can take advantage of the Rule of Zero.

Comment: Another thing is that `Character.h` is missing an include guard.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you, I tried to shorten the code and provided my main function I'm using for testing.  Also thank you for pointing out that my assignment overload was wrong.  After deleting that overload the sort works fine.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm aware of the time complexity implications but I'm preparing for an exam and my professor said to practice sorting a vector of a class by different attributes.  But thank you for the reading on the rules of 5, 3, and 0.  This will be helpful.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes when I initially posted my question I removed some comments from the start of my Character.h and apparently also deleted that.  However the include does exist in my code.

Comment: @inVain3219 No worries. I recommend scaling back a bit. Start with a really simple structure and sort that. No files. No user input, just a scrambled `vector` and a call to sort. Complicate as necessary until you have a program that remains as simple as possible while reproducing the bug. Often just doing removing the noise of the unnecessary code from the problem exposes the bug. What you have for your sort logic looks fine to me, suggesting that the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: Just a few additional points; you don't need to allocate a Character with `new` as it's stored by value in the vector; use `vec.push_back(Character(name, type,...))`, or more concisely `vec.emplace_back(name, type, ...)`.
The `#ifdef Hitboxes_h` include guard typically comes _before_ including any headers. You don't need to specify the default destructor. 
However, as @samar points out, your code actually works as expected :)

Comment: @inVain3219 -- Your previous edit contained a broken assignment operator.  The compiler default version of the assignment operator would have worked without error.  This is the danger of writing code when not necessary -- as soon as you implemented a broken assignment operator, assigning (which `std::sort` will be doing) becomes broken.

Comment: If you want multiple sorting strategies on a single batch of data, [Boost.MultiIndex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#multiple_sort) may be worth a look. Still, you may want to find your current bug first in case it's something unrelated to what you think it is.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with a permutation of your inputs. It does give the correct sorted result :

```
Caustic Defense 13      5
Gibraltar       Defense 10      8
Lifeline        Defense 8       5
Bloodhound      Scout   8       5
Pathfinder      Scout   10      6
Bangalore       Soldier 11      4
Mirage  Soldier 11      4
Wraith  Soldier 8       4
```